# Extract cell indicators from MeshRegion?

Tags: replacement, mesh

As of version 11.1, one can create successive steps of such objects as the Cantor ternary set and a Menger carpet (aka Sierpinski carpet) directly. For example:

```
     CantorMesh /@ Range[0, 2]
```

[image: Cantor meshes of order 0, 1, 2]

(*Aside:* To create a suitable image to insert here, the code I actually used was
`GraphicsColumn[
 CantorMesh[#, MeshCellStyle -> {Thick, Red}] & /@ Range[0, 2], AspectRatio -> 0.25]`.)

What I would like, instead of the several mesh pictures, are Boolean indicators of which sections of the original interval and, at each step, its subintervals, are retained and which are deleted. That is, I want to obtain the output:

```
{{1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}}
```

That is easy to do by using the built-in function `SubstitutionSystem`:

```
    SubstitutionSystem[{1 -> {1, 0, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}, 1, 2]
```

Or, going back to more basic functions, by:

```
    cStep[lis_] := Flatten[lis /. {1 -> {1, 0, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}]
    NestList[cStep, {1}, 2]
```

**Question** Is there a way to extract the same binary information directly from the result of `CantorMesh`?

And similarly for higher-level steps of the Cantor set and for the steps of forming the Menger carpet?

Answer (score 2):

Try to map the following function. It tests wether the interval midpoints are contained in the `MeshRegion` `R`, where `R` is assumed to be a `CantorMesh`.

```
find = R \[Function] Boole[RegionMember[R, MovingAverage[
 Transpose[{Range[0., 1., 3^-Log2[MeshCellCount[R, 1]]]}], 2]]]
```

PS.: For those of you who are not working on a Mathematica version 11.1 or above (just like me), here an implementation of `CantorMesh` using the function `cStep` from the OP.

```
cantorMesh = n \[Function] Module[{edges, cStep},
    cStep[lis_] := Flatten[lis /. {1 -> {1, 0, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}];
    edges = 
     Transpose[{Range[1, 3^n], Range[2, 3^n + 1]}][[
      Flatten@Position[Nest[cStep, {1}, n], 1]]];
    MeshRegion[Transpose[{Range[0., 1., 3^-n]}], Line[edges]]
    ];
```

Comment: Nice for `CantorMesh`, but not general enough to work, too, for `MengerMesh`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the similar idea that Henrik did:

```
iStep[r_?MeshRegionQ] :=
 Block[{n, dx, pts, grid, f, d, l, i, ind},
  l = First[Differences@RegionBounds[r][[1]]];
  dx = RegionMeasure[MeshPrimitives[r, {1, 1}]];
  n = l/dx;
  pts = N@Table[i dx + dx/2, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}];
  d = RegionEmbeddingDimension[r];
  ind = Table[{i[j], pts}, {j, d}];
  grid = Table[ind[[All, 1]], ##] & @@ ind;
  f = RegionMember[r];
  Boole[Map[f, grid, {d - 1}]]
  ]

iStep /@ Table[CantorMesh[i], {i, 0, 2}]
```

> {{1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}}

```
iStep /@ Table[MengerMesh[i], {i, 0, 2}]
```

> {{{1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>   1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1,
>   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
>   0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}

```
iStep /@ Table[MengerMesh[i, 3], {i, 0, 1}]
```

> {{{{1}}}, {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
>       0}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}}